# Changed location of OneDrive; now Office 2013 apps crash?

Tags: microsoft-office, crash, redirection, onedrive, microsoft-office-2013

My `C` partition is small; so I have moved `OneDrive` to a different partition.

This works fine when I used Windows 8.1's `SkyDrive` app to open documents stored there; and when I used Windows Explorer.

However when I click "My Name OneDrive" then "Documents" the program (be it Word, Visio, Excel etc.) crashes then relaunches itself.

How do I replace the path where Office 2013 looks for OneDrive with where my system looks for it?

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken about this, but Word 2013 "My Name OneDrive" doesnt actually check your local OneDrive, but shows a virtual folder to "https://d.docs.live.net/[user-id]/". So if you are unable to connect to this url, Word 2013 might crash, i would imagine.

Another possible source of error could be if you have moved one of your system folders to point to a OneDrive folder. I did that with my picture folder, moved the pointer of %userprofile%/pictures to point to /OneDrive/Pictures.
This caused modern-apps which featured picture upload to crash when i tried to browse pictures in both OneDrive and local folder. Might it be the same thing happening with you?